# remove data from laravel fractal

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.5

I'm using laravel-fractal to transform my data and here is a response

how can I delete **data**;
I made a search and I realized I need to use a Serializer;
But I just want to remove data for all includes(relations)

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "test name",
            "status": null,
            "tags": [
                "first",
                "second"
            ],
            "created_at": "1396/9/3",
            "contacts": {
                "data": [
                    {
                        "value": "test@test.com",
                        "type": "email",
                        "icon": "fa fa-email"
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "name test 2",
            "status": null,
            "tags": [],
            "created_at": "1396/9/3",
            "contact": {
                "data": []
            }
        }
    ]
```

Comment: I believe you are trying to do an API, and in this case, you really need the convention of having `data` as a response!

Comment: The question is why you need to remove the `data`? Don't you have a plan to have a pagination? You should paginate your data, then you'll need `data` resource key.

Comment: I don't have paginate for nested relation.

Answer (score 4):

I found my answer at GitHub. The following answer is copied from [thephpleague/fractal on GitHub](https://github.com/thephpleague/fractal/issues/251):

---

You can write your own serializer for that.

```
class YourDataSerializer extends ArraySerializer
{
    public function collection($resourceKey, array $data)
    {
        if ($resourceKey) {
            return [$resourceKey => $data];
        }

        return $data;
    }

    public function item($resourceKey, array $data)
    {
        if ($resourceKey) {
            return [$resourceKey => $data];
        }
        return $data;
    }
}
```

Register your serializer with manager

```
$manager = new Manager();

$manager->setSerializer(new YourDataSerializer());
```

and when you want to have data or anything else you can pass in resourceKey to your Item or Collection as a third param.

```
$resource = new Collection($folders, new AccountFolderTransformer(), 'data');
```

Comment: Thank you! I was searching for something that always return the extra 'data' parameter.

Answer (score 1):

use array serializer:

```
Fractal::create()
        ->item($item, new MyTransformer())
        ->serializeWith(new ArraySerializer())
```